# Pasar el valor de Input a un Controller mediante un Link

Tags: laravel, botón, controller, parametros

estoy realizando una página que permita buscar registros filtrando mediante un campo, en la imagen les muestro con mayor detalle:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya tengo definido el Controller que me devolverá los datos aplicando el filtro, lo que no se es como pasar el valor que escriba el usuario en el campo mediante el botón Buscar.
El botón Buscar en un link, pero también podría ser un button, pero creo que ahí tendría que usar un Form

Este es el Controller que querría usar:

```
    public function indexF($cadFiltros){
    $clientes = Cliente::orderBy('id', 'desc' )
        ->where('razSocial', 'LIKE', '%' . $cadFiltros . '%')
        ->paginate(15);

    return view('clientes.listaClientes',
        [
            'clientes'=>$clientes
        ]
    );
}
```

y este otro fragmento de código, muestra el campo y el botón para realizar las búsquedas:

```
<div class="flex w-full bg-gray-500 rounded mt-10 mb-5 p-2">
        <label class="form-label" for="cadBusquedas">Nombre del Cliente</label>
        <input class="form-camptextos" type="text" name="cadBusquedas" value="" placeholder="Cliente a buscar...">
        <a type="button" class="font-osw text-sm bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white text-center w-28 ml-3 p-2 pt-3.5 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="{{route('clientes.indexF', 'JUAN')}}">Buscar</a>
    </div>
```

Estoy parametrizando por código "JUAN", pero es solo a efectos de probar. Justamente, ahí es donde estoy trabado, como hago para enviar lo que el usuario escriba en el campo

Gracias y Saludos por vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En lo personal no te recomiendo mucho hacer eso, realizas muchas peticiones al servidor al cambiar cada vez el input, más en especifico, cuando añades o eliminas un carácter de la cadena que deseas filtrar. Ahora, ya que te comente esto, te recomiendo dedicar una vista exclusivamente para esto (mi gusto personal).

1.- Si no deseas que tu actualice una parte al realizar la búsqueda SIN refrescar la páginacompleta:
La opción que te muestro a continuación sirve para que se ejecute con cada cambio en el input, pero si deseas que esto no sea así, agrega un botón en tu buscador que en el evento "onclick" la función "Buscar()", de esta manera evitaras un poco muchas peticiones a tu servidor.

```
<div class="flex w-full bg-gray-500 rounded mt-10 mb-5 p-2">
  <label class="form-label" for="cadBusquedas">Nombre del Cliente</label>
  {{-- Utilizo el siguiente input con id buscador-clientes por temas de código limpio --}}
  <input class="form-camptextos" type="text" name="cadBusquedas" value="" placeholder="Cliente a buscar..." id="buscador-clientes"> 
  {{-- <input class="form-camptextos" type="text" name="cadBusquedas" value="" placeholder="Cliente a buscar..." onchange="buscar()">  --}}
  <a type="button" class="font-osw text-sm bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white text-center w-28 ml-3 p-2 pt-3.5 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="{{route('clientes.indexF', 'JUAN')}}">Buscar</a>
</div>


<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      dato1
    </tr>
    <tr>
      dato2
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="registros-busqueda">
    
    <tr>
      response.dato2
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>

  document.getElementById('buscador-clientes').onchange = buscar;
  function buscar(){
    const cliente = document.getElementById('buscador-clientes').value;
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../url", // Tu  URL o {{route('nombre de la ruta que asignaste en web.php')}}
    data:{
      cliente: cliente
    } , 
    dataType: "JSON",// Este campo no es necesario, puedes eliminarlo
    success: function (response) {
      // Aqui recibes tus datos en formato JSON normalmente
      let tabla = document.getElementById('registros-busqueda');
      tabla.innerHTML = `<tr>${response.dato1}</tr>`
      tabla.innerHTML += `<tr>${response.dato2}</tr>`
      tabla.innerHTML += `<tr>${response.dato3}</tr>`
    }
  });
  }
</script>
```

2.- Más fácil, realiza un buscador avanzado donde tu input lo tengas en un Formulario, realizas la petición a tu controlador al dar click en enviar (el submit de tu formulario), de esta manera evitas que el usuario realice peticiones a tu servidor de manera descontrolada. Pero claro, la página actualizara con cada envió de formulario.